# How to invoke the controller when you using ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller, action

Hi i have designed my code architecture using mvc\adr design pattern, but i am stuck with some problems:

1. I can invoke the controller using ajax request.
2. the view can invoke the controller using ajax request.

This is non ajax request
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference for controller whether request came from AJAX call or an ordinary browser refresh. The important part is that the response has to be different, which means that you should only have different view for standard vs ajax call (or maybe, just a different template).

For some reason, I am getting a feeling that your problem actually comes from some strange logic in your dispatcher logic.